# fluent nhibernate: set lazy loading in execution time?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

is it possible in Fluent NHibernate to enable or disable Lazy loading in execution time?
In some cases when I retrieve an object I need the Many relation to be lazy loaded and in other cases I don't want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You should map the association as lazy (this is the default), and when required, use a fetch load query.